# Event Listeners and Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a canvas element, where I have a set of rectangles and these rectangles need to move accordingly based on the selection of the arrow keys on the keyboard.

**index.html**

```
<canvas id="snakeCanvas" width="400" height="350"></canvas>
```

I am using the "keydown" event listener to toggle with this logic, I have the following piece of code in my **main.js** file

```
(function () {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        game.init();

        document.addEventListener("keydown", function (evnt) {
            var keyDirection = evnt.keyCode;
            if (keyDirection === "37" && direction !== 'right') {
                direction = 'left';
                console.log('test');
            } else if (keyDirection === '38' && direction !== 'down') {
                direction = 'up';
            } else if (keyDirection === '39' && direction !== 'left') {
                direction = 'right';
            } else if (keyDirection === '40' && direction !== 'up') {
                direction = 'down';
            }
        });
    });

})();
```

I am able to console out the **keyCode** value, but upon debugging I noticed that, the debugger does not step into the conditional logic. What am I missing?

Comment: Where is your `direction` variable defined? also if it doesn't have a value none of your conditions will return true...

Comment: @NewToJS I have a constants.js file where i have directions defined

Comment: Add `console.log(direction);` before your if condition and check it contains the expected string.

Comment: @NewToJS so by default i have direction set to "down" in constants file, and upon adding the console.log(direction) the direction always prints out "down" regardless of the arrow key i press

Comment: I think I have found the issue. Try swapping `===` for `==` in your conditions. [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/a7v777px/)

Comment: @NewToJS ok that worked thanks!!, but isn't === the right way in JS or unless I am missing something

Comment: Your current attempt will also work if you remove the quotes wrapping the integers. **Example:** `keyDirection === 37 && direction !== 'right'` [**Updated JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/a7v777px/1/)

Comment: Reason for this is because in your condition you are trying to compare an integer to a string. `evnt.keyCode` returns as a integer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `==`. `===` requires the objects to be of the same type. JavaScript however is loosey with `==`:

```
a=37;
b='37';
a==b //true
a===b //false
```